# How to dock a column of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scroll, docking

I have been checking around for an answer on docking a single column of a JTable like it is done in excel yet I could not come up with any solution. What I want to do is just docking the first column of the table.

Is this possible? To have a column like this on table or not?

Comment: Docking in what sense ? you don't want to move it?

Comment: I want to keep that column in view as user scrolls horizontally.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548139/how-can-i-create-a-jtable-where-the-first-column-is-always-in-the-jscrollpane-vi and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155137/how-to-keep-a-single-column-from-being-reordered-in-a-jtable?rq=1

Comment: now I see it that I could not find the question which had already been asked. Thanks @splungebob